# integral computed with respect to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal M_0$ be a $\sigma$-algebra that is contained in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal M$ of subsets of a set $X$, $\mu$ a measure on $\mathcal M$ and $\mu_0$ the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathcal M_0$. Let $f$ be a nonnegative real-valued function that is measurable with respect to $\mathcal M_0$ (and hence with respect to $\mathcal M$ as well). Then the set of all nonnegative simple functions $\phi\le f$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal M_0$ is a subset of the set of all nonnegative simple functions $\psi\le f$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal M$, and so
$$
\int_Xf\,d\mu_0\le\int_Xf\,d\mu.
$$
Can this inequality be strict?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you have equality.

This is because you can find a nondecreasing sequence of nonnegative, $\mathcal M_0$-measurable functions $(\phi_n)$ such that $\phi_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in X$. By the monotone convergence theorem applied to $\mu$ and $\mu_0$ it follows that $\int fd\mu=\int fd\mu_0$.

Comment: Thanks! This totally makes sense!

Comment: If we change the question to say "Let $f$ be a real-valued function...", dropping the adjective "nonnegative", do the integrals still have to be equal?  (I think the answer's yes, since you can probably just split $f$ up into positive and negative parts.)

Comment: Yes,the integrals remain equal, by splitting up indeed.

Comment: The functions $\phi_n$ must also be simple.

Comment: @user111 Agreed. If not, then this proof assumes the result!

Answer (score 8):

The intuition here is that integrating $\mathcal M_0$-measuarble function w.r.t. $\mu_0$ is actually integrating it w.r.t. $\mu$ since you are doing everything on the restriction where both measures agree. Let me provide a formal way of proving this: consider "two" measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal M)$ and $(X,\mathcal M_0)$ - this trick is often used in topology to study different typologies on the same set. You have that
$$
  \mathrm{id}:X\to X \quad\text{ given by }\quad \mathrm{id}(x) = x \;\forall x\in X \tag{1}
$$
is a $\mathcal M/\mathcal M_0$-measurable map, and so induces the [image measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) $\mathrm{id}_*\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal M_0)$ define by
$$
  (\mathrm{id}_*\mu)(A) = \mu(\mathrm{id}^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A) \qquad\forall A\in \mathcal M_0. \tag{2}
$$ 
From $(2)$ it is clear that we can represent $\mu_0 = \mathrm{id}_*\mu$, so that for any non-negative $f\in \mathcal M_0$:
$$
\begin{align}
  \int f\,\mathrm d\mu_0 &= \int f\,\mathrm d(\mathrm{id}_*\mu) &\text{from }(2)
  \\
  &= \int (f\circ \mathrm{id})\,\mathrm d\mu  &\text{change of variables}
  \\
  &= \int f\mathrm d\mu  &\text{from }(1)
\end{align}
$$
where we used the [change of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property%3a_Change_of_variables_formula) formula.

Perhaps, there may be a more basic proof - but I believe it is important to learn techniques of dealing with different structures on the same set using the $\mathrm{id}$ map.

Comment: Thank you! This is a little too advanced for me right now. But maybe I'll educate myself enough to understand it.

Comment: @mathreader: sure :) for some reason from your questions and answers I got a feeling that such level won't be of a much problem to you, but anyways. I've edited to give some intuition of what we are aiming to prove first.